# Azure Resource Group Set Tags with SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, resources, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I have used code similar to http://blogs.infinitesquare.com/b/tranise/archives/-azure-resource-group-une-nouvelle-facon-dorganiser-ses-environnements-dans-azure#.Vr1RrfIrLgk to create a Resource Group in Azure with C#. I am now trying to extend it by putting Tags on the Resource.

Adding `resourceGroupGetResult.ResourceGroup.Tags.Add("a","1")` works, but a subsequent CreateOrUpdateAsync call fails with

```
"InvalidRequestContent: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'provisioningState' on object of type 'ResourceGroupDefinition'. Path 'provisioningState', line 9, position 23.'."
```

What is the correct way to add Tags to a Resource Group? Of course I will want to add the same Tags to resources within the Group after this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the nuget package and version you're using?

Comment: Does the answer provided resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using nuget package id="**Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources**" version="**3.4.0-preview**".

The sample code for adding tag(s) to Azure Resource Group using the ARM .NET SDK above is as below:

```
var tag = new Dictionary<string, string> {{tagName, tagValue}};
var rg = new ResourceGroup() { Name = rgName, Location = rgLocation, Tags = tag };
await client.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(rgName, rg);
```

**Note**: This code sample should backward-compatible with older release version of the above-mentioned nuget package.

Hope this helps!