# How to Add Tags to Azure Resource from a C# - Web Application

Tags: c#, azure, tags

How can I add Tags to an azure resource using C# Code in my ASP.NET Application.
I am trying to create an azure tag management portal.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354412/azure-resource-group-set-tags-with-sdk)  but it is about adding a tag to a resource group . Also that Library seems deprecated. If any one knows how to attach a tag to a Resource, Please help.

Note: (i)I have tried the [Azure ServiceManagement API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn848368.aspx) but I see there is no API support for attaching a tag to a resource. (ii) Will powershell Cmdlets a viable option if nothing else works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone interested in a way to try out through REST API, 
I found this after spying on powershell bound traffic using Fiddler. Note the tag as json-payload.

**https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VM-Name}**

```
PATCH **https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/6dcd{subscrID}e8f/resourceGroups/css-dev/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/css-development/databases/css-dev?api-version=2014-04-01 HTTP/1.1**
Authorization: Bearer sDSEsiJKV1QiLCJhbG[<PARTIALLY REMOVED BY KIRAN FOR SECURITY REASON>]XDvZBJG5Jhh0rivehvDS
User-Agent: AzurePowershell/v1.0.0.0
ParameterSetName: Resource that resides at the subscription level.
CommandName: Set-AzureRmResource
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: management.azure.com
Content-Length: 52
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

**{
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "AzureV1"
  }
}**
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link to create client application in AD and service principle. Make note of tenantId, ClientId and ClientKey

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Find the resource, add / update tags and patch it.

```
var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientKey);
var resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCreds);
resourceClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

GenericResource genericResource = resourceClient.Resources.Get("some-resource-group", "Microsoft.DocumentDB", "", "databaseAccounts", "some-resource", "2016-03-31");

genericResource.Tags.Add("Version", "1.0");

resourceClient.Resources.CreateOrUpdate("some-resource-group", "Microsoft.DocumentDB", "", "databaseAccounts", "some-resource", "2016-03-31", genericResource);
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell could easily do this, you can use the command below:

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @( @{ Name="tag_name"; Value="tag_value" }) -ResourceId <resource_id>
```

Check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/) for details.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. azure powershell script execution form c# code will be something I need to explore now. :)