# How to Add Tags to Azure Subscription from a C# code?

Tags: .net, azure, tags

How to Add Tags to Azure Subscription from a C# ?

Unable to find CreateOrUpdate method for SubscriptionClient object.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SDK you're using (with version).

Answer (score 0):

​To set the tags attached  to the subscription [using c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.models.subscription.tags?view=azure-dotnet) , as below example:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="tags")] 
public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> Tags { get; set; }
```

**Please refer the below links for further information :**

- [Setting Tags On Subscriptions Using C#](https://www.stefanroth.net/2020/08/10/azure-functions-setting-tags-on-subscriptions-using-c/)
- We can tag the resource group using C# , Described in this [SO
  thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296013/how-to-add-tags-to-azure-resource-from-a-c-sharp-web-application)